# Dealing with broken images in the context of friendly URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I use the following `.htaccess` code to enable friendly URLs in a website.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

It works as it's supposed to but there's something that bugs me. When, let's say, I request a page that has a `<img src="sth.png" />` in it and `sth.png` does not exist on the server, the `.htaccess` code will instruct the server to make a request to `index.php?sth.png`, which would result in a completely unnecessary load of the whole framework of the website.

What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: You can certainly exclude certain extensions from being handled by the rewrite rules, but is this really that much of a problem? 404's shouldn't be the rule. Is your index.php not emitting a 404 if a resource can't be found?

Comment: Perhaps you should change your rule and exclude image files? But is it correct that you check if the file don't exist? Perhaps remove the "!" and check if the file exists.

Comment: @Pekka, if a requested page does not exist, the framework would emit a 404, but it would still load a bunch of things in order to show a proper 404 page.

Comment: @Emanuil yeah, but how often does it happen that an invalid *image* is requested? If that happens, you're going to fix the page that contains the broken reference as soon as possible, so this shouldn't be that much of a problem. (Anyway, it doesn't really matter. Either way will work fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.png$
```

should exclude PNG files from being subjected to the Rewrite rules.

But as said in the comment, I would consider handling 404s within index.php regardless of their type - they shouldn't happen so often that loading the PHP file becomes a performance issue anyway.